# Android Spinner taking time, after select value from adapter

Tags: android, android-spinner

In my application there are lot's of views(spinner, buttons, editText, textView, ImageButton etc).
After selecting one value in the spinner it not reflect the value which I selected. The old value is till there on the spinner. But when I tap on other views like editTest then spinner value automatically updated. 
I think no need to mention the code because normal spinner is there which populating data from ArrayAdapter and I am doing small task after selecting value.

CODE:-

```
spinnerWard = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerWard);
aAdapterWard = new ArrayAdapter<WardList>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listWard);
        aAdapterWard.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerWard.setAdapter(aAdapterWard);
spinnerWard.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int pos, long id) {
                intWardPosition = pos;
                intFinalWardId = listWard.get(pos).getId();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
        });
```

Comment: Why do you think that no code required here? Is not any bug into your code? \

Comment: I updated question with code. If bug is there then it will throw error. May be you right but the code is simple.

Comment: I don't see any problem here. Could you paste the entire code?

Comment: spinner part is only this much. Apart of this the code is very big and not able to mention here. Stackoverflow support only 30000 character.

Comment: May be it's taking time to load data